# which is the most appropriate java collection for 2 discrete pools

Tags: java

I have two collections - basically "unemployed" and "employed" objects.

when a new object is required, I check the unemployed collection - if there are any elements, one of them (doesn't matter which one, first, last, whatever) is removed from that collection and added to the employed collection.  if there are no elements in the unemployed collection, a new object is instantiated.

if an object is no longer being used, it's removed from the employed collection and sent to the unemployed collection.

what concrete java collection would be most appropriate?

order does not matter in either collection.

i need an `add()` method, a `size()` method and a `pop/poll()` type method.

so far, priority queue looks like the closest, but i don't care about insertion order (although i suppose it doesn't hurt).

tyia.

Comment: Not clear on why a hash or set wouldn't be more appropriate.

Comment: @DaveNewton i don't see a poll-type method on hashset - is there a particular implementation you'd recommend?

Comment: What is a "poll-type method"?

Comment: (Oh, I missed that it didn't matter which object was going to be "used" or moved, in that case a simple list implementation would be fine.)

Comment: @DaveNewton popping off (and returning) the first or last element...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like a [`LinkedList<E>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) would be entirely sufficient: it provides `add`, `size`, and an ability to add/remove from both ends (`addFirst`, `removeFirst`, `addLast`, and `removeLast`), all at `O(1)` cost.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight thanks - linkedlist certainly does what i need, as does priorityqueue - is linkedlist a more efficient implementation?

Comment: @BigMoMo Yes, linked list is more efficient, because unlike the priority queue it does not need to do comparisons: whatever went in last remains last until you add something on top or remove it; whatever went in first remains first until you remove it. The priority queue, on the other hand, must be smart about what it gives you back, so it performs re-orderings on insertions and deletions. It sounds like you do not care for the ordering, though, so there's no reason to spend CPU cycles doing the work that you do not need anyway.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight thanks for the info.  i'll accept as soon as it lets me (5 minutes)